# Create list of Seasons and Years as Constant Values

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, recursive-query

I want to generate a list of Seasons and Years, ie (`FA2019`, `WI2019`, `SP2019`, `SU2019`) for current year + 3 years ahead. This would then be fed into another query in the `WHERE` clause.

Right now I have 4 statements for each season that I just `UNION` them together. Is there a shorter way to do this?

```
SELECT 'FA' || YYYY AS SSYYYY FROM (
SELECT to_number(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))+LEVEL-1 AS YYYY FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4)

UNION

SELECT 'WI' || YYYY AS SSYYYY FROM (
SELECT to_number(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))+LEVEL-1 AS YYYY FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4)

UNION

SELECT 'SP' || YYYY AS SSYYYY FROM (
SELECT to_number(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))+LEVEL-1 AS YYYY FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4)

UNION

SELECT 'SU' || YYYY AS SSYYYY FROM (
SELECT to_number(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))+LEVEL-1 AS YYYY FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `CROSS JOIN` two `CONNECT BY` queries, like:

```
SELECT s.SS || y.YYYY AS SSYYYY
FROM 
(
    SELECT to_number(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')) + LEVEL - 1 AS YYYY 
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
) y
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DECODE(level, 1, 'FA', 2, 'WI', 3, 'SP', 4, 'SU') AS SS 
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
) s
ORDER BY y.YYYY, s.SS
```

Returns:

```
| SSYYYY |
| :----- |
| FA2019 |
| SP2019 |
| SU2019 |
| WI2019 |
| FA2020 |
| SP2020 |
| SU2020 |
| WI2020 |
| FA2021 |
| SP2021 |
| SU2021 |
| WI2021 |
| FA2022 |
| SP2022 |
| SU2022 |
| WI2022 |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c20f055c0e4db06c9bca6e77c9e5bd4)**

Answer (score 3):

Use `cross join` with `connect by level <= 4`

```
select season||year as seasons
 from
(
select 'SU' as season from dual union all
select 'WI' from dual union all
select 'FA' from dual union all
select 'SP' from dual  
)
cross join
(
select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy') + level - 1 as year
  from dual 
connect by level <= 4)
order by seasons;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/IVQJ9548)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
   SELECT DECODE(MOD(level, 4), 1, 'FA', 2, 'WI', 3, 'SP', 'SU') ||   
          TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE) + FLOOR((LEVEL-1) / 4))
     FROM DUAL 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 16;
```